# VLC RTSP Error - cannot Select open

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm reading a streaming from a DCS-2311L-ES. I'm able to view the RTSP feed using vlc rtsp://{ipaddr}/live1.sdp

It displays the image for about a few frames then displays

```
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[0000564f46b21570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default 
interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Created new TCP socket 32 for connection
[00007ffa40002ca0] egl_x11 gl error: cannot select OpenGL API
[00007ffa64019b70] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared 
Library  390.116  Sun Jan 27 06:28:58 PST 2019 for hardware decoding
^CQObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Any thoughts for what could be causing this? Is this related to the Graphics driver or the Network Camera?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: I have a camera stream I can see w/ VLC on my Debian sys, but on my Odroid Ubuntu I can't get VLC to work, and am also seeing this error, along with "main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented" about 25 lines before this.